# ScrollTo not working with grouped ListView in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a `TabbedPage` and it contains a few `ContentPage` that are consisting of a `ContentView` and some of them has a `ListView`.

The `ListView` contains a *grouped* `ItemsSource` represented by a custom model class:

```
public class DataGroup: List<DataGroupItem>
{   
    public string HeaderText { get; set; }

    public string ShortName { get; set; } 

    public string SubTitle { get; set; }

    public DataGroup(string headerText, string shortName)
    {
        HeaderText= headerText;
        ShortName= shortName;
    }
}
```

The XAML code (it has an ItemTemplate as well):

```
<ListView x:Name="listView"
              Grid.Row="0"
              GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding HeaderText}"
              GroupShortNameBinding="{Binding ShortName}"
              HasUnevenRows="True"
              IsGroupingEnabled="True"
              ItemsSource="{Binding DataGroups}"
              SeparatorColor="Black"
              SeparatorVisibility="Default">
    ...
</ListView>
```

When I change the actual tab, **I need the `ListView` to be scrolled to a certain group.**

I use this code:

```
ObservableCollection<DataGroup> dataGroups
    = this.listView.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<DataGroup>;
if (scrolling)
{        
    var res = dataGroups.Where(dg=>dg.ItemCount > 3).LastOrDefault();
    if (res != null)
        //Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(150), () =>
        //{
            this.listView.ScrollTo(res, ScrollToPosition.Center, false);
            //return false;
        //});
}
```

I tried all variations in `ScrollToPosition`, unfortunately, nothing happens.

What else should I try?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it was quite an adventure to figure this out.

First, I thought I should set a *child item* as the target of the `ScrollTo` method, but it changed nothing.

As a vague idea, I added the `SelectedItem` into the soup, and it worked, so I have this as a final result:

```
ObservableCollection<DataGroup> dataGroups= this.listView.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<DataGroup>;
if (scrolling)
{        
  var res = dataGroups.Where(dg=>dg.ItemCount > 3).LastOrDefault();
  if (res != null && res.Count > 0)
  {
    this.listView.SelectedItem = res[0];
    this.listView.ScrollTo(this.listView.SelectedItem, ScrollToPosition.MakeVisible, false);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to set also the group. You need to set both the group and the item, see example below:

```
listView.ScrollTo(item, group, ScrollToPosition.Start, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use res[0] instead of res, something like this:

```
ObservableCollection<DataGroup> dataGroups= this.listView.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<DataGroup>;
if (scrolling)
{        
  var res = dataGroups.Where(dg=>dg.ItemCount > 3).LastOrDefault();
  if (res != null && res.Count > 0)
  {
    this.listView.ScrollTo(res[0], ScrollToPosition.MakeVisible, false);
  }
}
```